# repl process died unexpectedly-Segmentation-fault core dumped

Tags: javascript, fetch, cloud, cloudinary

In replit I have made all the files. I am using Cloudinary to generate the URL of two images which is be to sent in the cloud API (those two images will generate a new image URL) which we will access with a get request. As this API is hosted in AWS I cannot disclose it.
I have used node js to fetch the URL in $@#%%/API to process the image in the cloud and it takes 40 seconds to complete and return success. The cloud contains a GAN model which generates a new image and saves the result as style.png in @##@%/result/.
My code looks like this:
This shows segmentation fault as soon as I select the image. Can anyone show or guide why this is occurring.

```
const Formidable = require("formidable");
var cloudinary = require("cloudinary").v2;
const fs = require("fs");
const express = require("express");
const path = require('path');
// mod.cjs
const fetch = (...args) => import('node-fetch').then(({default: fetch}) => fetch(...args));

// async function loadMyfetcher() {
//   const fetch = import("node-fetch");
//   // import fetch from 'node-fetch'
// }
// loadMyfetcher();

const FormData = require('form-data');
require("dotenv").config();

// Cloudinary configuration settings
// This will be fetched from the .env file in the root directory
cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUD_NAME,
  api_key: process.env.API_KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.API_SECRET,
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

//Create a server
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  const obj = {
    latestprod0imagelink: "images/banner.png",
    prod0head: "dress sale product on",
    prod0details: "sale is on for dress",
    prod0color: "black",
    latestprod1imagelink: "images/pic31.jpeg",
    prod1head: "sale biggest sale",
    prod1details: "biggest lakme cream",
    prod1color: "black",
    latestprod2imagelink: "images/banner.jpg",
    prod2head: "p2 head",
    prod2details: "p2 details",
    prod2color: "white"
  };
  res.render("index", obj);
});
app.get("/pd.html", (req, res) => {
  const indexdata = fs.readFileSync("frontend/templates/pd.html");
  res.send(indexdata.toString());
});
app.get("/pd1.html", (req, res) => {
  const indexdata = fs.readFileSync("frontend/templates/pd1.html");
  res.send(indexdata.toString());
});
app.get("/pd2.html", (req, res) => {
  const indexdata = fs.readFileSync("frontend/templates/pd2.html");
  res.send(indexdata.toString());
});

app.post("/upload", (req, res) => {
  const form = new Formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(404).send(`<h1>Sorry!! Requested page not found</h1>`);
    }
    cloudinary.uploader.upload(files.upload.filepath, function(error, result) {
      console.log(result);
      if (result != undefined) {
        const urlpass = result.url;
        //api fetch
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('style', 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=12X5T6_A9PfwJ0EBbEF5-wVbI5N3igaJ1');
        formData.append('img', urlpass);
        formData.append('type', '1');

       const res1= fetch("http://@$@$@#/api",
          {
            body: formData,
            method: "post"
          })
          .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
          }).catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
          });
        const modelres= fetch("http://!@$@#$#/result/",
          {
            body: formData,
            method: "get"
          })
          .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            return data.toString();
          }).catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
          });

        //render
        res.render("pdresult", { imagelink: modelres});
      }

      if (error) {
        res.status(404).send(`<h1>Sorry!! Some error occured</h1>`);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

[image: error]

Comment: Probably related to this issue and several others I found on github: 
https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/38695 
It looks like the problem stems from premature garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

After some experimentation, I found the following solution that works in all general use cases, including loading it as a file from repl.

```js
const fetch = (()=>{let f = import("node-fetch");return async (...args)=>await (await f).default(...args);})();
```

Also, if you are manually importing node-fetch in repl, the following code works as well since repl supports await on global scope

```js
> const fetch = (await import('node-fetch')).default;
...do something with fetch
```

## How it works

Let's look at the original idiomatic way of importing `node-fetch`

```js
const fetch = (...args) => import('node-fetch').then(({default: fetch}) => fetch(...args));
```

This code can be broken down like this using async/await syntax

```js
const fetch = async (...args) => {
    let {default: fetch} = await import('node-fetch');
    return await fetch(...args);
}
```

As you can see, this code imports `node-fetch` every time `fetch` is called. This is usually not a problem since `import` caches the result, but inside of repl, the content gets garbage collected due to a bug.

As a comparison, here is my code in a broken down form.

```js
const fetch = (() => {
    let f = import("node-fetch");
    return async (...args) => await (await f).default(...args);
})();
```

My solution differs in that it only calls `import` once, and reuses the module object every time `fetch` is called. This is achieved by storing the result as a promise inside an anonymous function scope, and awaiting that promise when the wrapper function is called. This promise will resolve immediately into a module object if the module is already loaded.